# Robots.txt, encrypted characters? Disallow: /azr94v2hh2lg/

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Anyone have ideas what is this? I found this in my robots.txt. Is this some kind of encrypted characters?

```
Disallow: /azr94v2hh2lg/
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this some kind of encrypted characters?

No, robots.txt does not support encryption. Apparently it's intended to be a non-existent URL to counteract a bug that some web crawlers were supposedly exhibiting many years ago.

I don't know what the original source for this is, it's entirely possible it is no longer online, but here is one source on the issue, which in turn references another site which does not appear to have this content anymore.

#### Excerpt from http://seoserviceguide.com/what-is-indexing-and-pagerank/ :

> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /azr94v2hh2lg/
> ```
>
> Note: this “/azr94v2hh2lg/” “tells Google as well as any other robot type search engine to stay out of your “/azr94v2hh2lg/” directory. Of course you do not have this directory on your Web server. By doing this we’re providing a real disallow directive which will keep search engines happy and not deliver any errors. You can replace the “/azr94v2hh2lg/” with any other directory name you wish just as long as the directory does not and will never be part of your Website and it will have the same effect.” – www.scrubtheweb.com.

Supposedly some crawlers would not properly crawl a website without a `robots.txt` file containing at least one non-empty `Disallow` entry, and this sequence of characters is the pseudo-random string somebody came up with to fulfill this purpose.

As for the validity for such claims, I cannot comment. I find there are loads of dubious rumors and unsubstantiated claims when it comes to SEO advice.

However if this was true, I am extremely doubtful this issue is still relevant.